# Is it possible for Google App Engine string and integer datastore keys to clash?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I have a datastore entity of kind `MyEntity` and I want to sometimes use [`StringID`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Key.StringID) keys and other times use [`IntID`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Key.IntID) keys generated by [`AllocateIDs`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#AllocateIDs).

Can I safely mix string and integer IDs without worrying that a string ID might surreptitiously overwrite an integer ID generated by `AllocateIDs` and vice versa?

The reason I ask is because I assume string and integer IDs use the same index. Is it possible to accidentally have a sequence of bytes that represent a string ID be the same as a sequence of bytes that represent an integer ID on the same index? Or are string and integer IDs namespaced in some way to prevent collisions?

Comment: Keys and indexes are completely different things. (And, for that matter, so are strings and integers.)

Comment: That is all true, but ultimately the strings and integers that make up the datastore keys are represented as sequences of bytes on an index in order for them to be retrieved efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can safely mix String & Int IDs for the same kind - just the same key (*entity*) can not use both at the same time. There is no danger of overlapping. I guess under the hood they use something like [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) to serialize a key to `[]byte`.

I used it like that in production without any issues.

Though it maybe not the best design but it really depends on your case.

Comment: There will be no over-writes in the Datastore itself, but you have to take care when you pass such IDs to your client and back, assuming that you allow String names that consist of integers only.